# Is it possible to automatically open pointers of the void* type?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, types

My task is to write a loop program that would take an array of void* pointers and determine what type of data they point to, below I gave an example of my program and I already understand what is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.
Here is the text of the assignment.

) Implement a library of functions for a dynamic array that stores
elements of type (void*) and automatically expands when trying
to add an element that does not fit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


void print_vector(const vector<void*>& User_vector) {
    for (const auto& element : User_vector) {
        if (element != nullptr) {
            if (int* int_possible_value = reinterpret_cast<int*>(element)) {
                cout << *int_possible_value << " ";
            }
            if (char* char_possible_value = reinterpret_cast<char*>(element)) {
                cout << *char_possible_value << " ";
            }
            if (double* double_possible_value = reinterpret_cast<double*>(element)) {
                cout << *double_possible_value << " ";
            }
        }
    }
} 


int main() {

    vector<void*> User_vector;

    int a = 1, b = 2;
    char d = 'k', e = 'n';
    double g = 1.23, h = 2.32;

    User_vector.push_back(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&a));
    User_vector.push_back(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&b));
    User_vector.push_back(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&d));
    User_vector.push_back(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&e));
    User_vector.push_back(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&g));
    User_vector.push_back(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&h));

    print_vector(User_vector);

    return 0;
 }
```

The problem is with the print_vector function(const vector<void*>& User_vector). When an array is fed into it, all the elements are fully disclosed as pointers to int. If I put the disclosure of pointers to char in the 1st place, then, accordingly, all elements will be output with the char type.

Comment: If all you have is a `void*` you can't determine what it points to.  This seems like a very silly C++ problem to solve considering you should not be using `void*`'s in C++.

Comment: You fix it by not using `void` pointers in the first place. They do not store **any** information about what they actually point to You clearly care about the types, so do not use `void` erase them.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<T*>` must be applied to a pointer that is either `nullptr` or points to a valid `T` object. Doing otherwise is UB and the compiler may assume it doesn't happen. Use `union` for such low-level tricks (or, better yet, don't use them at all).

Comment: Perhaps look at `std::variant` and `std::any`

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is "dumb" and doesn't do any type-checking. `dynamic_cast` only works for polymorphic types. With `void*`, you cannot do what you are asking... What exactly is the "task"? Perhaps you're misinterpreting it.

Comment: @Abstraction: type punning via unions is also UB, or did they change that recently? You must only access the one member that was written to.

Comment: @ThomasWeller No change made to unions in this regard, it's still UB to type pun through a union.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` always succeeds, which is why the first test is always positive.

Comment: @PeteBecker It's a bit more tricky: notice that other branches don't execute despite the lack of `else`. This is compiler and compiler-options-and-phase-of-the-moon dependent behavior but basically compiler "figures" `element` must actually be `int*` and then output must throw an exception or something since the expression in the second `if` will not be evaluated.

Comment: @Abstraction -- good point: I didn't notice that the `if's didn't have any `else`s. Nevertheless, my comment is correct: the first test is always positive. <g>

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create your own type that manually stores both data and its type in an object:

```
struct MyAnything {
  enum class Type {
    Int, Char, Double,
  } type;
  union {
    int int_val;
    char char_val;
    double double_val;
  } value;
  explicit MyAnything(int v) : type(Type::Int) {value.int_val = v;}
  explicit MyAnything(char v) : type(Type::Char) {value.char_val = v;}
  explicit MyAnything(double v) : type(Type::Double) {value.double_val = v;}
};

void print_vector(const std::vector<MyAnything*>& User_vector) {
  for (const auto& element : User_vector) {
    if(element == nullptr) continue;
    switch(element->type){
    case MyAnything::Type::Int:
      std::cout << element->value.int_val << " ";
    //and so on
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how we store both data and metadata in the object and then dispatch control flow based on metadata. No matter what method you employ, it *will* do something like this under the hood. `void*` is a simple pointer and doesn't store the info you need. Some things that do:

`std::any` is a [pre-written](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), more powerful version of the trick above;

Classical object-oriented solution would be to make your own class hierarchy:

```
class IPrintableValue {
public:
  virtual void print(void)const = 0;
  virtual ~PrintableValue() = default;
};
class PrintableInt : public IPrintableValue {
  int val;
public:
  explicit PrintableInt(int v) : val(v) {}
  virtual void print(void) const override {std::cout << val << " ";}
};
//...
void print_vector(const std::vector<IPrintableValue*>& User_vector) {
  for (const auto& element : User_vector) {
    //metadata is employed by the compiler: the call is actually something
    //like element->pVTable->print() where pVTable is created automatically
    if(element != nullptr) element->print();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `MyAnything` is more close to `std::variant` rather than `std::any`.